# How does PRAGMA table_info(table-name) work in SQLite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, pragma

I started learning SQLite and read that I can get the column information about any table with the `PRAGMA table_info(table-name)` command without specifying column names anywhere in the file.

How does `PRAGMA` know which columns we need for any particular table? Do we have to specify any information about the table in a bin file or environment file?

Comment: This is not a Ruby question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hima, you got everything upside down.

Of course, PRAGMA table_info returns columns of table - it's the purpose of this instruction.

How does it work:

1. `CREATE TABLE NewTable(col1 int, col2 text)` statement issued in sqlitedb at some point of time
2. In consequence of it metadata of sqlitedb is changed: a) 'NewTable' is added in table list, b) ('NewTable','col1'), ('NewTable','col2') is added to column list
3. Then somebody executes PRAGMA table_info(NewTable) - sqlite looks in metadata and extracts ('col1', 'col2')